# how many bullets have been fired?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I am super frustrated and I know it is just because I don't know what i am doing with cocos2d. I am following Ray Wenderlich tutorials on cocos2d and I am trying to put it all together. When the screen is tapped,one bullet is fired in the direction of the tap. I am using

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    [self.officer shootToward:touchLocation];
    [self.officer shootNow];
}

- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    [self.officer shootToward:touchLocation];
    [self.officer shootNow];
}
```

which calls these  methods in my Officer class

```
- (void)shootNow {
    // 1
    CGFloat angle = ccpToAngle(_shootVector);
    _gun.rotation = (-1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle)) + 90;

    // 2
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    float mapMax = MAX(winSize.width, winSize.height);
    CGPoint actualVector = ccpMult(_shootVector, mapMax);

    // 3
    float POINTS_PER_SECOND = 300;
    float duration = mapMax / POINTS_PER_SECOND;

    // 5
    for(id item in self.children) {
    NSString *bulletName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bullet.png"];
    CCSprite * bullet = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:bulletName];
    //bullet.tag = _type;
    bullet.position = ccpAdd(self.position, ccpMult(_shootVector, _gun.contentSize.height));
    CCMoveBy * move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:duration position:actualVector];
    CCCallBlockN * call = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
        [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }];
    [bullet runAction:[CCSequence actions:move, call, nil]];
    [self.batchNode addChild:bullet];

        //[self addChild:bullet];
        [_shotsFired addObject:bullet];
    }
}
```

So I figured it would be a simple for loop go through the 5th step x amount of times then call a reload method. Well that didn't work. So  I tried to count the touches on the screen, I figured if I got x amount of taps then call the reload method(which is not written yet)? The problem with that was every time you pressed a different area of the screen the count started over from one. Some please help me through this week long process of pulling my hair out? How do I count the amount of times I have fired the gun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just make a property on your view controller and then every time the shoot now method is called just add 1 to your property, then reset it to 0 when you call the reload method?